# Unity/C#: How to increase item friction without increasing air resistance?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I've just started making a 2d physics based game but when I tried to set up a catapult thing to check some features I noticed the projectile started to slide off but when I turned up the friction it also turned up the air resistance, how do I increase friction without increasing air resistance?

Comment: What is it from air resistance that bothers you? Isn't that just adding friction depending on velocity?

Comment: Because it travels slowly through the air and cant be launched as right after it is slightly of the catapult at the beginning it becomes an immovable object so the the catapult stops and the projectile isn't launched it just floats down from a couple pixels high.

Comment: Have you tried playing with RigidBody's `drag` property, or `angularDrag` if it "rolls out" of the catapult? Also, how did you set your catapult's and projectile's respective`RigidBody`s? Maybe the shape of the catapult is also to blame? In a nutshell : can you help us reproduce the problem you're having? Without any code and details, this question will be hard to answer, and probably off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Have you played with the various values of friction here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicMaterial.html ? Note that you may want to use a friction for the catapult and not for the projectile, and use the proper combination of both.

Comment: Do you actually have friction if you manually place the object somewhere in the air? Possibly it is the catapul friction that holds it in place. In that case maybe you can just work around this by switching the physics material as soon as the catapult is actually fired.

Answer (score 0):

In Unity, there are only two values that describe friction. Linear drag, and Angular drag.

- Linear drag - describes how fast the object velocity is slowing down per tick
- Angular drag -  describes how fast the object rotation is slowing down per tick

I think you would need a little script to achieve different drags in different enviroments, pseudo-code would look like this

```
if(in_the_catapult)
{
    // Set the rigidbody to high value to not slide off
    rigidbody.drag = 100;
}
else if(touching_the_ground)
{
    // Set the rigidbody to what the friction should be on the ground
    rigidbody.drag = 2;
}
else if(in_the_air)
{
    // Set the rigidbody to what the air resistant should be 
    rigidbody.drag = 0.1;
}
```

This code should run in Update to check every frame if the state has changed or it should be run on the event if the condition has changed because it's probable that your bullet will bounce off the ground multiple times.